# Inno Setup cannot launch .exe in System32

Tags: windows, iis, inno-setup, system32

I'm using Inno Setup to make an installer for my program. I would like to run IIS Manager after installation. So, I'm using this code:

```
[Tasks]
Name: StartAfterInstall; Description: Run IIS after install;

[Run]
Filename: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe"; \
    Description: "launching IIS prova"; \
    Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent; Tasks: StartAfterInstall;
```

This should open IIS manager, but it doesn't work, returning me this error:

> Could not execute file C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe
> CreateProcessor failed, code 2 , file not found"

Using same code, but running other .exe file in a different path works. Does this depend on this specific path: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv`?

Answer (score 3):

There's probably only 64-bit version of the `InetMgr.exe`.

As Inno Setup in a 32-bit application, it by default [gets redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) (32-bit version of `C:\Windows\System32`). If there's no 32-bit version of `InetMgr.exe` in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, Inno Setup cannot find it.

Add the [`Flags: 64bit`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=64bit) to make Inno Setup find 64-bit version of the the `InetMgr.exe`.

Or use the [64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

---

Side note: Do not hard-code `C:\Windows\System32`, as that path can be different on some systems. Use [`{sys}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=sys).

---

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe"; Flags: 64bit; ...
```